# In TradingView widget chart (With our own datafeed) how to setup exact from and to date?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

In the implementation of a Trading View Widget chart with our own data feed, the getBars function automatically defines the date range for the chart. However, I would like to set a specific date range for the chart instead of using the default range. How can I modify the code to achieve this customization?

In the implementation of a Trading View Widget chart with our own data feed, the getBars function automatically defines the date range for the chart. However, I would like to set a specific date range for the chart instead of using the default range. How can I modify the code to achieve this customization?

Code Snippet:

```
  var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
            debug: true,
            symbol: 'QNBK',            // Default symbol pair
            interval: '1D',                        // Default interval
            fullscreen: true,                      // Displays the chart in the fullscreen mode
            container: 'tv_chart_container',       // Reference to the attribute of the DOM element
            datafeed: Datafeed,
            library_path: 'charting_library/',
            "timezone": "Asia/Kuwait",

 });
        widget.onChartReady(function () {

            var chart = widget.chart();

            chart.setVisibleRange({
                from: Date.UTC(2018, 7, 1) / 1000,
                to: Date.UTC(2020, 1, 1) / 1000
            });
        });

//Datafeed.js

export default {

    onReady: (callback) => {
        console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
   
        setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData));
    },

    searchSymbols: async (
        userInput,
        exchange,
        symbolType,
        onResultReadyCallback
    ) => {
        console.log('[searchSymbols]: Method call');
      },

    resolveSymbol: async (
        symbolName,
        onSymbolResolvedCallback,
        onResolveErrorCallback,
        extension
    ) => {
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Method call', symbolName);
        if (symbolName === null || symbolName=="") {
            console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Cannot resolve symbol', symbolName);
            onResolveErrorCallback('Cannot resolve symbol');
            return;
        }
       

        // Symbol information object
        const symbolInfo = {
            ticker: symbolName,
            name: symbolName,
            description: 'QNB',
            type: 'stock',
            session: '24x7',
            timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
            exchange: 'QSE',
            minmov: 1,
            pricescale: 100,
            has_intraday: true,
            has_no_volume: false,
            has_weekly_and_monthly: false,
            supported_resolutions: configurationData.supported_resolutions,
            volume_precision: 2,
            data_status: 'streaming',

          
        };
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Symbol resolved', symbolName);
        onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
    },
   
    getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
        const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
        console.log('[getBars]: Method call', symbolInfo, resolution, from, to + ";periodParams.countBack:" + periodParams.countBack);
      
        try {
            
            const data = await GetSnapshotData(symbolName);
                if (data === null || data.length <= 0) {
                    // "noData" should be set if there is no data in the requested period
                    onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
                    return;
                }
                let bars = [];
                data.forEach(bar => {
                    //if (bar.Date >= from && bar.Date < to) {

                        const dateString = bar.Date; // Example "YYYYMMDD" string
                        const year = parseInt(dateString.substr(0, 4));
                        const month = parseInt(dateString.substr(4, 2)) - 1; // Subtract 1 from the month as it is zero-based
                        const day = parseInt(dateString.substr(6, 2));

                        const fromDate = new Date(year, month, day);

                        const fromTimestamp = fromDate.getTime();

                        let price = bar.Price;
                        var rndVal = 0.85;
                        var rndValH = 0.5;
                        var basePrice = price;
                        var openNoise = (0.1 - Math.random() * 0.2) + rndVal;
                        var closeNoise = (0.1 - Math.random() * 0.2) + rndVal;
                        var openP = basePrice * openNoise;
                        var closeP = basePrice * closeNoise;
                        var highP = Math.max(basePrice * (0.45 + Math.random() * 0.1), openP, closeP);
                        var lowP = Math.min(basePrice * (1 - Math.random() * 0.1), openP, closeP);


                        bars = [...bars, {
                            time: fromTimestamp,
                            low: lowP,
                            high: highP,
                            open: openP,
                            close: closeP,
                            volume: bar.Volume
                        }];
                   // }
                });
                if (firstDataRequest) {
                    lastBarsCache.set(symbolInfo.full_name, { ...bars[bars.length - 1] });
                }
                console.log(`[getBars]: returned ${bars.length} bar(s)`);
                onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[getBars]: Get error', error);
            onErrorCallback(error);
        }
    },
    
        subscribeBars: (
        symbolInfo,
        resolution,
        onRealtimeCallback,
        subscriberUID,
        onResetCacheNeededCallback
    ) => {
        console.log('[subscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
           
    },
   

    unsubscribeBars: (subscriberUID) => {
        console.log('[unsubscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
        unsubscribeFromStream(subscriberUID);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also am after very similar
I see the documentation for getBars https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/connecting_data/Datafeed-API#getbars

And the reference to the interface for PeriodParams https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/api/interfaces/Charting_Library.PeriodParams

I hope this helps, but i am also unsure how or where to set the interface for PeriodParams

I will update when i find the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sivakumar (are you still reading this)

I have or had the same problem as you (in my case i want to be able to pick date/times for back trading), so setting the periodParams within this range is what i "think" i needed.

I cannot find in the documentation how to set periodParams as it seems to be defined as a constant, using your browsers date....
However after various methods, i found the really simple one was to add `var periodParams ={stuff}` just inside getBasrs, so it overwrites the periodParams constant with a variable...

```
getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
    var periodParams = {
        from: 1668639600000,
        to: 1668675540000,            
        countBack: 301,
        firstDataRequest: true,            
    };
... other stuff },
```

works perfect, although with the TradingView.widget debug set to debug: true,
this shows it is still looking for data from the current browser date/time.

I am sure there will be a better way of doing this and i will ask on the tradingView github page. if i get a better method or more official way of setting the dates, i will update here.

I hope this helps